# How do i implement a half slider like this with jquery and css?

Tags: jquery, image, css, slider

did you see Microsoft surface home page? There are two oblique cutted panel which react on mouse hover and fulfill the width of the screen. How do i implement it using jQuery and CSS?

Is there any library or jQuery plugin? It's really confusing. I don't even know the name of this component is it a slider or it is a spitted panel or what?

### [image]

Comment: Have you tried opening your browser's console? We're not here to implement nice effects from around the web.

Comment: Yes i did, and searched a lot, but i saw the similar effect in other sites too, i thought sure it is something and it's not unique to Microsoft website, but i don't know what component or technique is this and you may know. do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called the `skewslider`

YOu can buy here [**Skew Slider**](https://skewslider.com/)

For free your code is here [**Free slider effect skew**](http://jsfiddle.net/8dRe4/3/)

This can be done using css3 using **skew** transformation property!